# Entity Framework - Code First not generating associated collections in the Database

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm using CTP5 of the code first. Take the following simple class and associated DbContext

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Keywords = new Collection<string>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Keywords { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext()
    {
        Database.Delete();
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {       
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' 
in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration
.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'

Any ideas how to create the necessary table relationships between test class and the keywords property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class `Keyword` and change `ICollection<string> Keywords {get; set;}` to `ICollection<Keyword> Keywords {get; set;}`

```
public class Keyword
{
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

and code model creating like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Keyword>()
        .HasKey(x => x.Data);
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Just imagine, that you have 2 collections 1 - Keywords, 2 - Tags. Your realization would map it to same table, because in ORM mapping type defines entity. And both `Keyword` and `Tag` are of type string. So to split this entities you should split types.

Comment: Thanks, but why must a create a class for this?  There is no way to infer the relationship from ICollection<string>?

Comment: Not sure, but I think, that you should add classes for all data you store, because You map POCO objects to DB, not base-types.

Comment: Thanks this works, however how can i drop the Test.Id from the keywords table and make the Test class relationship be based on a FK on Keywords.Id?

Comment: Add `int Id {get;set;}` to `Keyword` class and simply remove overriding for `OnModelCreating`